# SpreadsheetGear - check if IRange has values

Tags: .net, range, spreadsheetgear

How can I check if specific SpreadsheetGear IRange contains values (=Non-blank cells)?

In Excel, I could utilize [COUNTA](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/counta-HP005209027.aspx) function but there is no such in SpreadsheetGear.

Answer (score 1):

SpreadsheetGear does support the COUNTA function.  You can input it as part of a formula directly into a cell.  Or you can use the ISheet.[EvaluateValue](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.ISheet~EvaluateValue.html)(...) method to evaluate a formula without actually entering it into a cell.  Example:

```
// Count the number of non-empty cells in A1:A12 on the specified worksheet
double count = (double)worksheet.EvaluateValue("COUNTA(A1:A12)");
```

You could build your own count routine using SpreadsheeGear API as well.  The code below might be a good starting-out point:

```
int counter = 0;
foreach (IRange cell in worksheet.Cells["A1:A12"])
{
    if (cell.ValueType != SpreadsheetGear.ValueType.Empty)
        counter++;
}
```

Comment: In my case, I had string concatenation formulas that produced an empty text result, but this is not the same as `SpreadsheetGear.ValueType.Empty`. What worked for me was `if (cell.Text != string.Empty)`.